# Eigenvector for specific eigenvalue

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues

I can't find guidance in the documentation center for how to retrieve the eigenvector(s) of a matrix associated to a specific eigenvalue. My first question is what the command is to do that. I would next like to apply that function to a list (I want all the eigenvectors associated to 0 in a list of matrices). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about `NullSpace /@ matrices`?

Comment: `NullSpace`? For other eigenvalues, `Eigensystem` gives a matching pair of eigenvalues and -vectors, so you can find the index of the eigenvalue you want and extract the corresponding eigenvector.

Comment: Thank you, NullSpace is perfect here since I'm looking for 0 and works. What if I wanted it for something else, say 1? How would I apply that to a list in a quick way? With the map function?

Comment: Or `Extract[#[[2]], Position[#[[1]], 1.]] &@*Eigensystem /@ matrices`.

Comment: @JungHwanMin at that point why not just use `Eigensystem` and then `Pick[#[[2]], #==testVal&/@#[[1]]]`

Comment: Thanks all, I will experiment with these. Very new to coding so seeing all the different options is very helpful.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Welp, I had this tab open for a while and didn't see the other answers.

Comment: If you don't like messing with pure functions and such: `Apply[Last, GroupBy[Thread[Eigensystem[matrix]], First], {2}]`. This method probably faster and easier to understand.

Comment: @massy255 How big are your matrices? Are you interested in symbolic results, or numeric ones are fine?

Comment: This really needs a specific example. Absent that, maybe `Eigensystem[matrix,-1]` will do what is wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting comment into answer:

You could define a function like this:

```
eigenAssoc[matrix_] := Apply[Last, GroupBy[Thread[Eigensystem[matrix]], First], {2}]
```

For example:

```
In[1]:= assoc = eigenAssoc[{{2, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}]

Out[1]= <|2 -> {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}, 1 -> {{0, 1, 0}}|>
```

Then you can use the resulting association to find the eigenvectors associated with an eigenvalue:

```
In[2]:= assoc[1]

Out[2]= {{0, 1, 0}}
```

If you expect to search some non-eigenvalue, then you may want to use [`Lookup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html):

```
In[3]:= Lookup[assoc, 3, {}]

Out[3]= {}
```

Comment: How do I apply assoc[1] to a list? Say I have Blocks = {{{1, 0}, {0, 5}}, {{-1, 3}, {0, 3}}, {{2, 2}, {0, 1}}}. eigenAssoc/@Blocks works fine, but not assoc[1]/@Blocks

Comment: @massy255 You could define a pure-function, like `eigenAssoc[#][1]& /@ Blocks`.

Comment: Thanks! How would I modify it so that it gives me an empty set when there is no desired eigenvector for one of the blocks? For example on the above it gives me {{{1, 0}}, Missing["KeyAbsent", 1], {{-2, 1}}}. (I would like to eventually union this set at the end of the day to get the whole eigenspace.

Comment: @massy255 Like in my third example, you would need to use `LookUp`. For example `LookUp[eigenAssoc[#], 1, {}]& /@ Blocks` (by the way, I highly recommend that you use lowercase or lowerCamelCase for variable names because all Mathematica built-ins are in UpperCamelCase; you would prevent any issues with variable naming).